# Numpy-thonic way to set elements given un-ordered input and corresponding IDs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of values `a`, and an array of unique IDs `ids` of the same length of a.

I then have a smaller array of values `v` and a corresponding array of IDs `v_ids` that must overwrite values of `a` where the IDs do match.

#### Small Example

For instance:

```
a   = [0,1,2,4,4,2,0,0]
ids = [7,1,0,8,9,4,3,6] #unique ids
v = [-1,-2]
v_ids  = [4,8]
```

I would then modify `a` given `v` and `v_ids` in order to obtain

```
a   = [0,1,2, -2, 4, -1,0,0] # I set values of `a` with values of `v` when ids == 4 and 8
```

#### Un-efficient solution

Here follows a non numpy-thonic and very slow way to solve this problem

```
def set_from_ids(a, ids, v, v_ids):
    result = np.array(a)
    for vid,value in zip(v_ids,v):
        index_of_vid_in_a = np.where(ids==vid)
        result[ index_of_vid_in_a ] = value
    return result


a   = np.array([0,1,2,4,4,2,0,0])
ids = np.array([7,1,0,8,9,4,3,6]) #unique ids
v = np.array([-1,-2])
v_ids  = np.array([4,8])

print(set_from_ids(a, ids, v, v_ids))
```

returns

```
[ 0  1  2 -2  4 -1  0  0]
```

#### Caveats when implementing numpythonic solution

Note that both the `ids` and `v_ids` arrays are not sorted which makes it difficult to implement a solution bases on masks.

#### Question

What is the numpy-thonic way to set elements given un-ordered input and a corresponding  array of unique IDs?

Comment: Are the ID's in v_ids assured to exist in ids? or could it be that they might not exist?

Comment: Yes, they always exists @ChrisDoyle

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about performance or efficency but you could just make a map of ids to values for both a and v. then update the main id map with the v_ids map.

```py
a   = [0,1,2,4,4,2,0,0]
ids = [7,1,0,8,9,4,3,6] #unique ids
v = [-1,-2]
v_ids  = [4,8]

id_map = dict(zip(ids, a))
v_map = dict(zip(v_ids, v))
id_map.update(v_map)
print(list(id_map.values()))
```

**OUTPUT**

`[0, 1, 2, -2, 4, -1, 0, 0]`